# arrays in puppet

Tags: arrays, file, resources, puppet

I'm wondering how to solve the following puppet problem: I want to create several files based on an array of strings. The complication is that I want to create multiple directories with the files:

```
dir1/
    fileA
    fileB
dir2/
    fileA
    fileB
    fileC
```

The problem is that the file resource titles must be unique. So if I keep the file names in an array, I need to iterate over the array in a custom way to be able to postfix the file names with the directory name:

```
$file_names = ['fileA', 'fileB']
$file_names_2 = [$file_names, 'fileC']

file {'dir1': ensure => directory }
file {'dir2': ensure => directory }

file { $file_names: path = 'dir1', ensure =>present, }
file { $file_names_2: path = 'dir2', ensure =>present, }
```

This wont work because the file resource titles clash. So I need to append e.g. the dir name to the file title, however, this will cause the array of files to be concatenated and not treated as multiple files...

arghh..

```
file { "${file_names}-dir1": path = 'dir1', ensure =>present, }
file { "${file_names_2}-dir2": path = 'dir1', ensure =>present, }
```

How to solve this problem without the necessity of repeating the file resource itself.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. You can take this as an example and modify according to your exact needs

```
class common_setup::test {                                                                                                                                                             

   file {'/var/tmp/dir1': ensure => directory }                                                                                                                                         
   file {'/var/tmp/dir2': ensure => directory }                                                                                                                                         

   $file_names = ['fileA', 'fileB']                                                                                                                                                     
   $file_names_2 = unique(flatten([$file_names, 'fileC']))                                                                                                                              
   common_setup::makeDirs { $file_names_2 :}                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                      

define common_setup::makeDirs {                                                                                                                                                        
   include common_setup::test                                                                                                                                                           

   if ($name in $file_names) and ($name in $file_names_2) {                                                                                                                             
      file { "/var/tmp/dir1/$name" :                                                                                                                                                     
        ensure => present,                                                                                                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                                                                                  

      file {"/var/tmp/dir2/$name" :                                                                                                                                                      
        ensure => present,                                                                                                                                                               
      }                                                                                                                                                                                  
   }                                                                                                                                                                                    
   else {                                                                                                                                                                               
     file {"/var/tmp/dir2/$name" :                                                                                                                                                      
       ensure => present,                                                                                                                                                               
     }                                                                                                                                                                                  
   }                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

test succeeded :

```
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/File[/var/tmp/dir2]/ensure: created
notice:   /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/Common_setup::Makedirs[fileA]/File[/var/tmp/dir2/fileA]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/Common_setup::Makedirs[fileC]/File[/var/tmp/dir2/fileC]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/Common_setup::Makedirs[fileB]/File[/var/tmp/dir2/fileB]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/File[/var/tmp/dir1]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/Common_setup::Makedirs[fileB]/File[/var/tmp/dir1/fileB]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]/Common_setup::Test/Common_setup::Makedirs[fileA]/File[/var/tmp/dir1/fileA]/ensure: created
notice: Finished catalog run in 1.97 seconds
```

and the directory along with files are created :

```
ls /var/tmp/dir*/
/var/tmp/dir1/:
fileA  fileB

/var/tmp/dir2/:
fileA  fileB  fileC
```